# Activate toggling on a single button by using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to activate toggling on a single button by using http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons

What I would like to do is… to hide/show a view when I click on the button and toggle the state of the button changing his text.

Here is my code (1). It hides/show the view but it does not change the text on the button. 
How should I do it using bootstrap?

```
createToggleButton = function (parentElement) {
    var buttonElement = $(document.createElement('button'));

    buttonElement.text('Customize');
    buttonElement.prop('class', 'btn');
    buttonElement.attr('type', 'button');
    buttonElement.attr('data-toggle', 'button');
    parentElement.prepend(buttonElement);

    buttonElement.on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(event.currentTarget).parent('div').find('.control-group').toggle(function () {
            buttonElement.text('new message'); // it changes just the first time,
                               // then I would like to set the original message;
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for your toggle option why don't you do:

```
$(event.currentTarget).parent('div').find('.control-group').toggle(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.btn').attr('value','First text you want');
},function(){
    $(this).show();
    $('.btn').attr('value','Second text you want');
});
```

Comment: your code does not work...are you sure you can pass two callbacks to toggle function ? I updated my question.